# Why won't Spring MVC app display?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc

Here is my app project structure:

```
myapp/
    src/main/java/
        com.me.myapp.controllers.HelloController
    src/main/config/
        mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
        web.xml
        pages/
            Hello.jsp
    lib/
        <JARs>
    build.xml
```

My `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean name="/hello.htm" 
            class="com.me.myapp.controllers.HelloController" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My `web.xml`:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
        version="2.4">
    <display-name>Partner Demo</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is the structure of the packaged WAR (after I bundle it up with Ant):

```
myapp.war
    META-INF/
    WEB-INF/
        classes/
        lib/
        pages/
            Hello.jsp
        mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
        web.xml
```

When I deploy this to Tomcat and go to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/hello.htm` I get a 404 Not Found error from Tomcat.

**Edit**: The objective is (obviously) to go to that URL and see my `Hello.jsp` page.

Where am I going wrong?

**Update**: my `HelloController`:

```
public class HelloController extends AbstractController {
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Hello");
        model.addObject("msg", "This should be visible.");

        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself: what does a bean name have to do with handling requests?

Comment: Also, show us your controller class. Also, consider upgrading to a newer version of Spring and a newer version of the Servlet api.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis (+1) - however I can't make much sense of your comment. I have updated my question with my `HelloController`, any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: You're using a seriously old version of Spring. Can't you upgrade?

Comment: Sure I can upgrade @SotiriosDelimanolis - but is that the root of the problem? Or does my code look fine and you are just suggesting I should upgrade (best practices, less headaches, etc.)? If you are just making a suggestion about upgrading, then where were you heading when you posed: "*What does a bean name have to do with handling requests?*"? Thanks again

Comment: You should definitely upgrade for new features and easier configurations. My original comment was related to the MVC configuration. In newer versions of spring you wouldn't eat the handling path as a bean name. I don't know I'd that is the case for older Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In web.xml file you need to change * into *.htm

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
        version="2.4">
    <display-name>Partner Demo</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Why do you think this is valid? What is /*.htm meant to match and why do you think so?

Comment: Yay, thanks @GaneshJadhao (+1) - you win the prize. Thanks again for just simply answering the question I posed!